# Starting a graphical application using sfml on Raspberry Pi boot

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, sfml, raspbian

I would like to make a Graphical interface for a home-made program using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) on Raspberry Pi2. I am using Raspbian. I recompiled the graphical lib

It works fine unsing `startx` first, then using my application, which wors perfectly fine.

But I can't figure if it is possible or how to launch my application directly after boot without launching startx (just to optimise the cpu of the Raspberry).

Starting my program direcly after boot, I get the following error:

```
Failed to open X11 display: make sure the DISPLAY environnement variable is set correctly.
Aborted.
```

I already tested the classic `export DISPLAY=:0.0` but without sucess.
I interested myself in [x](http://linux.die.net/man/7/x) and xinit, but I am not sure that would even do it.

Where should I start looking? I don't need a complete solution, even a hint or an idea would be nice!

Comment: This isn't strictly speaking about programming, so might be a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)  or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: making sfml work without an X server will be serious work. you would need to write a display driver, maybe some `fb` (direct framebuffer) style. And modify sfml to use that, rather than using X's API during window initialization. that would be crazy work even for an expert.

Answer (score 0):

I checked to see if it was possible to [open a graphical app without the X desktop environment](https://superuser.com/a/407053) and as that answer states, with Firefox at least, you need the X server which SFML also probably needs in order to create a window.

The answer states:

> Basically something like:
>
> ```
> $ X
> ```
>
> Then you just start Firefox in this X server:
>
> ```
> $ DISPLAY=:0 firefox
> ```
>
> You can switch from the X server and the framebuffer by using
>   CTRL+ALT+F1 and CTRL+ALT+F7.

You could try that and see if it helps.

Also, still searching, I found a [forum post on the sfml website](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15723.0) about what you're trying to accomplish stating somewhere:

> SFML requires OpenGL, so as far as I know you need at least X running,
>   but you probably don't need gnome, KDE or a similar Desktop
>   Environment on top.

The forum guy asking for help seems to have managed to get X11 and a SFML basic render window to work on Ubuntu server after someone posted a link to [xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc). I guess, that's the route to go from here.